# Unable to call a command on windows server by connecting through linux

Tags: expect

I am using a following script which connects to windows server from Linux, but after connecting i have to call the a command by doing to a location under D: drive of windows followed by some folders (Where the Folder names consists of spaces eg: d:\Rakesh Tatineni\not able to execute\Manager.exe 1 1)

Above is the some how i want to execute/call a command with 2 argument 1 1.

Script using to connect to windows

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
# Expect script to supply username/admin password for remote ssh server
# and execute command.
# This script needs three argument to(s) connect to remote server:
# password = Password of remote Windows server, for Windows user.
# For example:
#  ./call_engine.sh password
# set Variables
set password [lrange $argv 0 0]
set timeout -1
# now connect to remote windows box (ipaddr/hostname) with given script to execute
spawn ssh userid@<WindowsserverName> 
match_max 100000
# Look for passwod prompt
expect "*?assword:*"
# Send password aka $password
send "$password\r"
# send blank line (\r) to make sure we get back to gui
send "\r"
expect eof
```

Appreciate your help , in between what kind of code we have to include to call a command as i mentioned above "d:\Rakesh Tatineni\not able to execute\Manager.exe 1 1"

Thanks,
Rakesh T

Answer (score 0):

I see that you already give the script an argument of password. So you can change your script slighlty to add two more arguments like this:

```
set password [lrange $argv 0 0]
set arg1 [lrange $argv 1 1]
set arg2 [lrange $argv 2 2]
```